# How to handle different data for KMeans: standardize, drop, or something else?

Tags: python, k-means, data-preprocessing

I'm going to build a KMeans model which has is using records with different datatypes. I plan to use feature scaling to standardize the money amounts (like last 3 periods, rolling year value). For other amounts, like the number of years active, would I do the same? Finally, I have 0/1 bit data. I assume I should remove them.

Is this the right approach for this data? Thanks.

Edit:
Added picture of data

[image: data example]

Comment: There is missing columns in the data screenshot.